# Public function not returning error message when file not found

Tags: php

The following code is my template engine and it works great, with the small exception when a tpl file is not found the page should echo the error message "Error! Can't load the template file $templateFile".

```
namespace Template;

class Template
{
    private $tags = [];

    private $template;

    public function __construct($templateFile)
    {
        $this->template = $this->getFile($templateFile);

        if (!$this->template) {
            return "Error! Can't load the template file $templateFile";
        }
    }

    public function render()
    {
        $this->replaceTags();

        echo $this->template;
    }

    public function set($tag, $value)
    {
        $this->tags[$tag] = $value;
    }

    public function getFile($file)
    {
        if (file_exists($file)) {
            $file = file_get_contents($file);
            return $file;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private function replaceTags()
    {
        foreach ($this->tags as $tag => $value) {
            $this->template = str_replace('{'.$tag.'}', $value, $this->template);
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

I expect, when a matching .tpl file is not found the page should display "Error! Can't load the template file $templateFile", the actual output is a blank page.

Comment: You cant return anything from constructor. __construct() is a void function, see https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php
Try throw an Exception instead, maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Constructors are void function, Viod function means that can not return anything so you can't use return statement in constructor.

Instead of passing parameter in a constructor, Make a function for it and use return statement in that function

```
public function checkFile($filename)
    {
        $this->template = $this->getFile($filename);

        if (!$this->template) {
            return "Error! Can't load the template file $filename";
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Make an Object of class and call that function

```
$obj = new Template;

$filexists = $obj->checkFile($filename);

if(!$filexists){
  echo $filexists;
}
```